# How to get the summed value associated with unique variables in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, feature-engineering

I have a data set where "LR" is the value associated with a respective "diagnosis":

| personUID | diagnosis_type_code | LR | diagnosis |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc123 | icd10_1 icd10_4 | 2.5 | icd10_1 |
| abc1234 | icd10_4 icd10_5 | 5.5 | icd10_4 |
| abc1235 | icd10_4 icd10_5 | 10.0 | icd10_5 |

Each "diagnosis_type_code" has an associated "LR" value but there are multiple values in "diagnosis_type_code" column for each "personUID" while  each individual "diagnosis" has 1 value per row. Basically, I want to create a new column called "LR_Sum" that takes the sum of all the "diagnosis_type_code"per each "personUID". I'm not sure how to do that since "diagnosis_type_code" has multiple inputs per row while "diagnosis" has only 1 value per row.

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

The output should look like this:

| personUID | diagnosis_type_code | LR | diagnosis |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc123 | icd10_1 icd10_4 | 8.0 | icd10_1 |
| abc1234 | icd10_4 icd10_5 | 15.5 | icd10_4 |
| abc1235 | icd10_4 icd10_5 | 15.5 | icd10_5 |

Comment: Please provide an example of what the output should look like for your sample input data.  Also, please include any code you have tried and indicate why this code is not suitable.  In other words, provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I updated what the output should look like but I have not written any substantial code. I'm not exactly sure how to approach the problem at hand.

Comment: I don't understand how you are doing the grouping here.  Why does the first line get combined with the second?

Comment: Each personUID has associated diagnosis_type_codes and these diagnosis_type_codes have associated LR values. The LR values map to the diagnosis variable which is essentially the same variable as diagnosis_type_code but the diagnosis column does not map exactly to personUID like the diagnosis_type_code column does. I want the codes in diagnosis_type_code column to have the correct sum of LR values for each unique personUID

Answer (score 0):

This will take a few steps

First we split and explode 'diagnosis_type_code':

```
df2 = df.set_index('personUID')['diagnosis_type_code'].str.split().explode().reset_index()
```

df2 looks like this:

```
    personUID    diagnosis_type_code
--  -----------  ---------------------
 0  abc123       icd10_1
 1  abc123       icd10_4
 2  abc1234      icd10_4
 3  abc1234      icd10_5
 4  abc1235      icd10_4
 5  abc1235      icd10_5
```

Then we merge `df2` with the LR info:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df[['diagnosis', 'LR']], how = 'left', left_on = 'diagnosis_type_code', right_on = 'diagnosis')
```

`df3` looks like this:

```
    personUID    diagnosis_type_code    diagnosis      LR
--  -----------  ---------------------  -----------  ----
 0  abc123       icd10_1                icd10_1       2.5
 1  abc123       icd10_4                icd10_4       5.5
 2  abc1234      icd10_4                icd10_4       5.5
 3  abc1234      icd10_5                icd10_5      10
 4  abc1235      icd10_4                icd10_4       5.5
 5  abc1235      icd10_5                icd10_5      10
```

now we `groupby` on personUID and aggregate:

```
df3.groupby('personUID').agg({'diagnosis_type_code':' '.join, 'diagnosis':'first', 'LR':sum })
```

output:

```
personUID    diagnosis_type_code    diagnosis      LR
-----------  ---------------------  -----------  ----
abc123       icd10_1 icd10_4        icd10_1       8
abc1234      icd10_4 icd10_5        icd10_4      15.5
abc1235      icd10_4 icd10_5        icd10_4      15.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Really appreciate the thorough answer.